# Cold Fusion, <cfdocument How do you set up permissions

Tags: permissions, coldfusion, cfdocument

I attempted to create a PDF document using cfdocument:

```
<cfdocument
format = "PDF"
filename = "#session.exploc#/mypdf.pdf"
localURL = 'yes'>
 This is my document.
</cfdocument>
```

The document turned up in the proper place but I was not able to open it.  I got the message: "error opening file: Permission denied".

The documentation gives a cfdocument parameter as:
permission = "permission list".  The details of "permissions ="  show various text options such as "Allow printing".

I want to use the PDF file as an attachment in an email.  What permissions do I need for that so that the user will be able to open and print the document?   And what permissions do I need to be able to simply open the file in my browser?

Comment: Just a note to anyone who wishes to help that adding some number of the text-type permissions seems to work.  They should be separated by commas and the whole thing enclosed in quotes.  Not sure which permissions worked, but I'm not fussy.